# XSL for-each filter with subcontext from other main-node

Tags: xslt, merge, xslt-2.0

i've already a new problem.
I have to merge lists via xsl, problem on this is that the key in the lookup-list must be concatinated by 2 values. 
The lists can be relative large with thousands,ten-thousands in some cases even more of entries in both lists. In advance of large sizes of this lists, i have to look on performance and memory. It could be that this will later implemented in an web-service-client, so it must run quick and resource-saving.

Merging the exisiting Elements in List1 and List2 is done and was not complicated, but now i have to check both lists on non-exisiting elements in other list.
I tried to negate the for-each select statement but failed and it is presumably the wrong way.

InputXML-example

```
<ROOT>
    <getObjectListResponse>
        <item>
            <Key>1111111:aaaa</Key>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Key>2222222:bbbb</Key>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Key>3333333:aaaa</Key>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </item>
    </getObjectListResponse>
    <LookupList>
        <DATA>
            <KeyPart1>1111111</KeyPart1>
            <KeyPart2>aaaa</KeyPart2>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <KeyPart1>1111111</KeyPart1>
            <KeyPart2>bbbb</KeyPart2>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <KeyPart1>2222222</KeyPart1>
            <KeyPart2>aaaa</KeyPart2>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <KeyPart1>2222222</KeyPart1>
            <KeyPart2>bbbb</KeyPart2>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <KeyPart1>3333333</KeyPart1>
            <KeyPart2>aaaa</KeyPart2>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <KeyPart1>3333333</KeyPart1>
            <KeyPart2>bbbb</KeyPart2>
            <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
        </DATA>
    </LookupList>
</ROOT>
```

The first part, find the existing parts in both lists is already done.
The second part is to find non-existing parts in List 1 to List 2 and List 2 to List 1.
I wanna like to do this in for-each, so you get only non-exisiting entries from List1 which does not exists in List2. 
My Problem ist to lookup in for-each context with an concatinated key, from all DATA in LookupList.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/getObjectListResponse/item[Key/text() != /*/LookupList/DATA/*[concat(KeyPart1,'/',KeyPart2)]]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>           
            </xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="/*/getObjectListResponse/item[Key/text() != /*/LookupList/DATA/[concat(KeyPart1,'/',KeyPart2)]]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>           
            </xsl:for-each>
```

But everything i tried fails, with no results or wrong result.

How can this be done?

I tried this and some others, but nothing will work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use keys for the cross-reference, here is an XSLT 3.0 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 all editions or Altova XMLSpy/Raptor) stylesheet as obviously one sample is a good use case for a composite key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="data" match="DATA" composite="true" use="KeyPart1, KeyPart2"/>

    <xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="Key"/>

    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <items-not-in-data>
                <xsl:copy-of select="getObjectListResponse/item[not(key('data', (substring-before(Key, ':'), substring-after(Key, ':'))))]"/>
            </items-not-in-data>
            <data-not-in-items>
                <xsl:copy-of select="LookupList/DATA[not(key('item', concat(KeyPart1, ':', KeyPart2)))]"/>
            </data-not-in-items>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your sample data I get

```
<ROOT>
   <items-not-in-data/>
   <data-not-in-items>
      <DATA>
                              <KeyPart1>1111111</KeyPart1>
                              <KeyPart2>bbbb</KeyPart2>
                              <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
                    </DATA>
      <DATA>
                              <KeyPart1>2222222</KeyPart1>
                              <KeyPart2>aaaa</KeyPart2>
                              <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
                    </DATA>
      <DATA>
                              <KeyPart1>3333333</KeyPart1>
                              <KeyPart2>bbbb</KeyPart2>
                              <someOhterData>Text</someOhterData>
                    </DATA>
   </data-not-in-items>
</ROOT>
```

Of course XSLT 3.0 and a composite key is not mandatory, you could as well use XSLT 2.0 and use a single key value `concat(KeyPart1, KeyPart2)`.